# Select where datetime is greater than other datetime which may not exist

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a field `eventtime` of type datetime and a different table with a datetime field.

I need the minimum `eventtime` that is greater than the greatest datetime field from the other table which may not have any rows. If there are no rows in the other table, I just need the minimum eventtime.

My query is

```
SELECT
    min(eventtime) time_min
FROM
    `cel`
WHERE
    eventtime > (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(other_datetime), 0) FROM `call`)
```

This gives me exactly what I want. The problem is there are about 6.5 million records in the table and this query takes about 10 or 11 seconds to run.

I tried using other values instead of `0` in the coalesce such as an empty string, and `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` thinking that a type conversion was causing a performance hit, but those did not help at all.

mysql explain for the query
[image: mysql explain for the query]

- Should I add an index on the eventtime field?
- Is `0` an appropriate value to compare against a datetime field?
- If not, what is the right way to represent the minimum datetime value for comparison?
- Is there a better way to achieve this to optimize for execution time?

Comment: Does the indexes `call (other_datetime)` and `cel (eventtime)` exists? Or at least the last one...

Comment: *Is 0 an appropriate value to compare against a datetime field?* It may be incompatible to current SQL_Mode. Some constant literal value less than `MIN(cel.eventtime)` is more safe (for example, `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'`).

Comment: There are currently no indexes for the datetime fields on either table.

Comment: Create index by `cel (eventtime)`. `Call` table is compact enough, and selecting maximal field value using fullscan should not cause to visible performance degrade.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the `COALESCE` out of the subquery, to make it sargable:

```
        SELECT  min(eventtime) time_min
            FROM  `cel`
            WHERE  eventtime > 
                COALESCE( ( SELECT  MAX(other_datetime)
                                   FROM  `call` ), 0)
```

And indexes:

```
call:  INDEX(other_datetime)
cel:   INDEX(eventtime)
```

That should be able to use both indexes to good advantage and take essentially zero time.

If there is an issue with `0` not being a date, try `"0000-00-00"`

Comment: Performance aside, moving COALESCE outside the sub-select will work for an empty call table. In the OP:s query the result of the sub-query will be null if there are no rows in call. I.e your answer is an improvement for the logic as well